# 8 byte array back to long (C# to c++)

Tags: c#, c++, bitconverter

I'm converting a long to a 8 slot byte array with C#

`Byte[] Data = BitConverter.GetBytes(data.LongLength);`

For example if `data.LongLenght` is 172085, I get the following array { 53,160,2,0,0,0,0,0 }
But then after I send this to my c++ server I would like to get it to a long again.

I tryed this but without success...

```
long fileLenght = 0;
for( int i=0;i < 8; ++i)
    fileLenght = (fileLenght << 8) + Data[i];
```

Comment: It is stored little-endian, you have to iterate backwards.  Note that a C++ *long* isn't the same as a C# long, you need long long.  The kind of tricky details that make it a good idea to *not* send binary data across a wire.

Comment: What @HansPassant says.  You should define a byte-by-byte protocol so that the peer can always reassemble your data, no matter want language/version/whatever is receiving it, (and detect message boundaries too - your 8-byte message may not arrive in one recv call).

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93ae9768%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The order of bytes in the array returned by the GetBytes method depends on whether the computer architecture is little-endian or big-endian.

It looks like on your hardware the array is sent with its least significant bytes first. Therefore, you should start your loop from the end of the array:

```
int64_t fileLenth = 0;
for( int i=7;i >= 0; --i)
    fileLenght = (fileLenght << 8) + Data[i];
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/Klqt2m) (prints 172085)

In order to achieve better compatibility with C# you should use a [system-independent 64-bit integral type](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html) instead of `long`, i.e. `int64_t`.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you send data across a network you **have to** mind [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

In your case, it looks like the proper way to recreate the long from the byte array would be to reconstruct it from right to left:

```
long fileLength = 0;
for( int i=7; i >= 0; i--)
    fileLength = (fileLength << 8) + Data[i];
```

But this will not always be the case. Depending on the hardware and operating system at the end points, and the network transfer protocols you use you may have data coming in big-endian or little-endian format, and the receiving end may be little-endian or big-endian.

Comment: 'Whenever you send data across a network you have to mind endianness' - not really, no.  You have to mind a suitable protocol to ensure your data can be interpreted correctly.

Comment: @MartinJames - I think we're talking about the same thing - by virtue of choosing a protocol that helps you deal with endianness you are keeping it in mind (or at least acknowledging it). Either way it is important to know what not all systems and mediums represent multi-octet values the same way and set your expectations accordingly (my 2c)

Answer (score 0):

If both ends have the same byte order (C# is always little-endian, probably your C++ is also):

```
long long fileLength;
memcpy(&fileLength, Data, 8);
```

The optimizing compiler will almost certainly turn that into a single 64-bit move, so don't worry that it looks like an expensive function call.